# JavaFX demora para abrir a primeira vez

Tags: java, javafx

Eu possuo uma classe para GUI relativamente complexa que herda de Tab. Quando eu crio uma instancia dela , ela constrói os menus e GUI no código direto, sem **fxml**. 
Ela usa ícones em png externo, mas o programa faz o carregamento dos ícones logo no inicio.

O problema é que toda a primeira vez que instancio a classe(usando o construtor que chama o método de construção), o programa da um parada significativa, dai em diante, todas as instancias são extremamente leves, mesmo passando pelo método pesado.

Sendo , que eu tentei fazer um construtor vazio,  mas continua com a lentidão na primeira vez que usa o método pesado!